# How do I create a web/wcf service client in C++?

Tags: c++, webservice-client

I'm using NSIS to build an installer and as part of that installer I get the details for a WCF Service (i.e. Url, User Name and Password). I need to validate these details.

In C# I create a Service Reference and simply do the following:

```
var proxy = new ServiceClient(httpsBinding, serviceEndpointAddress);
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;

try
{
    proxy.Open();
}
catch (EndpointNotFoundException ex)
{
    // Return the end point's not valid
}
etc
```

Now I need to do this in C++ so it can be called from NSIS (I've investigated methods of calling C# from NSIS and they all seem to be overkill for what I want to do). I've managed to convert the code that generates the binding and the end point address however I'm stuck on creating the `ServiceClient`.

I've added a "Web Reference" to the project but there's not the equivalent of `ServiceClient` in the `ServiceReference` namespace. This:

```
ServiceReference::ServiceClient ^service = gcnew ServiceReference::ServiceClient(httpsBinding, endpointAddress);
```

doesn't compile as:

> 'ServiceClient': is not a member of 'ServiceReference'

So how do I create the client?

Comment: Have you put the `using namespace ServiceMainNamespace` directive relative to the web service you added ?

Comment: @alexbuisson - I can't seem to find that namespace. Can you add a link to the documentation.

Comment: Ok sorry, that namespace doesn't exist :) it was just an example to recall that in C# the ServiceClient class come from an assembly, and you should be able to found its name. Thaa assembly should be in the reference list of your C++/CLI and in the .cpp file where you use `ServiceClient`you must put a using directive. As in C# !

Comment: @alexbuisson - ah, I see what you're driving at. However I'm using the fully qualified name already. All I've got is something called `ServiceReference::Service` but that doesn't have any of the methods I'm expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with using the NSIS ["Call .NET DLL methods plugin"](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Call_.NET_DLL_methods_plug-in) which was really overkill for what I needed to do, but I needed a solution that worked and I ran out of time.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried gSOAP?

http://gsoap2.sourceforge.net/

that's what we're using to access WS* from C++ programs.

Comment: I don't really need anything that complex. All I need to do is verify the url, user name and password. I don't need to get any data.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a nice work around,
Create a C# DLL, use regasm to register this DLL, 
then you can use it from your C++ program.

Comment: This is overkill for something that's only called once from the installer just to validate the account details.